# How to change Grid.js state from the plugin?

Tags: javascript, preact, gridjs

How can I change state of the [Grid.js](https://gridjs.io/) component from the plugin context?

I'm trying to implement a visual configurator for the `pagination.limit` prop (https://gridjs.io/docs/config/pagination):

```js
import { BaseComponent, BaseProps, h, PluginPosition } from 'gridjs';

class LimitConfigurator extends BaseComponent {
    setLimit(limitNew) {
        // this.setState({ pagination: {limit: limitNew}});
        // this.config.pagination.limit = limitNew;
    }

    render() {
        const self = this;

        return h(
            'div',
            { class: 'limit-configurator' },
            [
                h('span', { onclick: function () { self.setLimit(10); } }, '10'),
                h('span', {}, '25'),
                h('span', {}, '50'),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

It renders something like `10 | 25 | 50` under the grid's footer and dynamically sets new per-page number for the `pagination.limit` path in the original component. Registration code:

```js
// somewhere in the Vue component (using gridjs-vue bridge)...

async mounted() {
    await elementReady('.grid-operator', { stopOnDomReady: false });

    const gridComponent = this.$refs.gridReference.$data.grid;

    gridComponent.plugin.add(
        {
            id: 'limitEditor',
            component: LimitConfigurator,
            position: PluginPosition.Footer,
        },
    );

    gridComponent.forceRender();
},
```

I see prop values in the `this.config` but don't know how to properly manipulate them from the plugin (currently learning preact + vue environment). Is there a "convenient" way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've found a solution. But here is my take as I recently came across this and figured.

In a plugin which extends the base component, we have access to `this.config`. On `this.config` we have `eventEmitter` property. We can `emit` events and listen on the `grid` object which we originally created as `gridjs` has a global EventEmitter object.

Eg:

```
const grid = new Grid({
  columns: ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone Number'],
  sort: true,
  search: true,
  data: [
    ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444'],
    ['Eoin', 'eo3n@yahoo.com',   '(05) 10 878 5554'],
    ['Nisen', 'nis900@gmail.com',   '313 333 1923']
  ]
});

grid.on('custom-event', data => console.log(data));
```

From your plugin method, you can just emit the 'custom-event' like `this.config.eventEmitter.emit('custom-event', 'foobar')`